# C# AWS S3 upload file fails sometimes

Tags: c#, asp.net, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am using an AmazonWebServices S3 bucket to upload images in an ASP.NET web application. The thing is that sometimes I get a null object exception while uploading an image. In the code snippet bellow you can see how it is done:

```
using (client = Amazon.AWSClientFactory.CreateAmazonS3Client(GlobalValues.ACCESS_KEY_S3_BUCKET,
                    GlobalValues.SECRET_KEY_S3_BUCKET, Amazon.RegionEndpoint.USWest2))
                {
                    PutObjectRequest request = new PutObjectRequest();
                    request.InputStream = file.InputStream;
                    request.BucketName = GlobalValues.BUCKET_NAME;
                    request.CannedACL = S3CannedACL.PublicRead;
                    request.Key = "Images/image.jpg";

                    client.PutObject(request);
                }
```

The line where the exception is thrown is: `request.CannedACL = S3CannedACL.PublicRead;`

I have been trying to solve it for several hours but I cannot reach a solution. Has anyone experienced something similar? Most of the times it fails when I have a session running in the ASP.NET app for several minutes. Any suggestions? Maybe it is due to a temporary failure in the S3 bucket?

Thanks in advance.